# Could not find java.beans.propertydescriptor on android

Tags: java, android

my app uses another projects which contains references to classes as java.beans.propertydescriptor which is not contained by android libraries.
The situation is the next: my project contains the .jar files with this another projects as libraries. I read that the solution is use an opensource class. I found it, but i dont know how can i add this class to the android .jar file. So, how can i add this class to the android java.beans library?
This is the class i have found:

```
package java.beans;

import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import java.util.Vector;
import org.apache.harmony.beans.internal.nls.Messages;

public class PropertyDescriptor extends FeatureDescriptor {
private Method getter;
private Method setter;
private Class<?> propertyEditorClass;
private boolean constrained;
private boolean bound;

public PropertyDescriptor(String propertyName, Class<?> beanClass,
        String getterName, String setterName) throws IntrospectionException {
    super();
    if (beanClass == null) {
        throw new IntrospectionException(Messages.getString("beans.03")); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    if (propertyName == null || propertyName.length() == 0) {
        throw new IntrospectionException(Messages.getString("beans.04")); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    this.setName(propertyName);
    this.setDisplayName(propertyName);
    if (setterName != null) {
        if (hasMethod(beanClass, setterName)) {
            setWriteMethod(beanClass, setterName);
        } else {
            throw new IntrospectionException(Messages.getString("beans.20")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
    }
    if (getterName != null) {
        if (hasMethod(beanClass, getterName)) {
            setReadMethod(beanClass, getterName);
        } else {
            throw new IntrospectionException(Messages.getString("beans.1F")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
    }
}

public PropertyDescriptor(String propertyName, Method getter, Method setter)
        throws IntrospectionException {
    super();
    if (propertyName == null || propertyName.length() == 0) {
        throw new IntrospectionException(Messages.getString("beans.04")); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    this.setName(propertyName);
    this.setDisplayName(propertyName);
    setWriteMethod(setter);
    setReadMethod(getter);
}

public PropertyDescriptor(String propertyName, Class<?> beanClass)
        throws IntrospectionException {
    String getterName;
    String setterName;
    if (beanClass == null) {
        throw new IntrospectionException(Messages.getString("beans.03")); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    if (propertyName == null || propertyName.length() == 0) {
        throw new IntrospectionException(Messages.getString("beans.04")); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    this.setName(propertyName);
    this.setDisplayName(propertyName);
    getterName = createDefaultMethodName(propertyName, "is"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    if (hasMethod(beanClass, getterName)) {
        setReadMethod(beanClass, getterName);
    } else {
        getterName = createDefaultMethodName(propertyName, "get"); //$NON-NLS-1$
        if (hasMethod(beanClass, getterName)) {
            setReadMethod(beanClass, getterName);
        }
    }
    setterName = createDefaultMethodName(propertyName, "set"); //$NON-NLS-1$
    if (hasMethod(beanClass, setterName)) {
        setWriteMethod(beanClass, setterName);
    }
    if (getter == null && setter == null) {
        throw new IntrospectionException(Messages.getString(
                "beans.01", propertyName)); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
}

public void setWriteMethod(Method setter) throws IntrospectionException {
    if (setter != null) {
        int modifiers = setter.getModifiers();
        if (!Modifier.isPublic(modifiers)) {
            throw new IntrospectionException(Messages.getString("beans.05")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = setter.getParameterTypes();
        if (parameterTypes.length != 1) {
            throw new IntrospectionException(Messages.getString("beans.06")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        Class<?> parameterType = parameterTypes[0];
        Class<?> propertyType = getPropertyType();
        if (propertyType != null && !propertyType.equals(parameterType)) {
            throw new IntrospectionException(Messages.getString("beans.07")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
    }
    this.setter = setter;
}

public void setReadMethod(Method getter) throws IntrospectionException {
    if (getter != null) {
        int modifiers = getter.getModifiers();
        if (!Modifier.isPublic(modifiers)) {
            throw new IntrospectionException(Messages.getString("beans.0A")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = getter.getParameterTypes();
        if (parameterTypes.length != 0) {
            throw new IntrospectionException(Messages.getString("beans.08")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        Class<?> returnType = getter.getReturnType();
        if (returnType.equals(Void.TYPE)) {
            throw new IntrospectionException(Messages.getString("beans.33")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
        Class<?> propertyType = getPropertyType();
        if ((propertyType != null) && !returnType.equals(propertyType)) {
            throw new IntrospectionException(Messages.getString("beans.09")); //$NON-NLS-1$
        }
    }
    this.getter = getter;
}

public Method getWriteMethod() {
    return setter;
}

public Method getReadMethod() {
    return getter;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    boolean result = (object != null && object instanceof PropertyDescriptor);
    if (result) {
        PropertyDescriptor pd = (PropertyDescriptor) object;
        boolean gettersAreEqual = (this.getter == null)
                && (pd.getReadMethod() == null) || (this.getter != null)
                && (this.getter.equals(pd.getReadMethod()));
        boolean settersAreEqual = (this.setter == null)
                && (pd.getWriteMethod() == null) || (this.setter != null)
                && (this.setter.equals(pd.getWriteMethod()));
        boolean propertyTypesAreEqual = this.getPropertyType() == pd
                .getPropertyType();
        boolean propertyEditorClassesAreEqual = this
                .getPropertyEditorClass() == pd.getPropertyEditorClass();
        boolean boundPropertyAreEqual = this.isBound() == pd.isBound();
        boolean constrainedPropertyAreEqual = this.isConstrained() == pd
                .isConstrained();
        result = gettersAreEqual && settersAreEqual
                && propertyTypesAreEqual && propertyEditorClassesAreEqual
                && boundPropertyAreEqual && constrainedPropertyAreEqual;
    }
    return result;
}

public void setPropertyEditorClass(Class<?> propertyEditorClass) {
    this.propertyEditorClass = propertyEditorClass;
}

public Class<?> getPropertyType() {
    Class<?> result = null;
    if (getter != null) {
        result = getter.getReturnType();
    } else if (setter != null) {
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = setter.getParameterTypes();
        result = parameterTypes[0];
    }
    return result;
}

public Class<?> getPropertyEditorClass() {
    return propertyEditorClass;
}

public void setConstrained(boolean constrained) {
    this.constrained = constrained;
}

public void setBound(boolean bound) {
    this.bound = bound;
}

public boolean isConstrained() {
    return constrained;
}

public boolean isBound() {
    return bound;
}

boolean hasMethod(Class<?> beanClass, String methodName) {
    Method[] methods = findMethods(beanClass, methodName);
    return (methods.length > 0);
}

String createDefaultMethodName(String propertyName, String prefix) {
    String result = null;
    if (propertyName != null) {
        String bos = propertyName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase();
        String eos = propertyName.substring(1, propertyName.length());
        result = prefix + bos + eos;
    }
    return result;
}

Method[] findMethods(Class<?> aClass, String methodName) {
    Method[] allMethods = aClass.getMethods();
    Vector<Method> matchedMethods = new Vector<Method>();
    Method[] result;
    for (Method method : allMethods) {
        if (method.getName().equals(methodName)) {
            matchedMethods.add(method);
        }
    }
    result = new Method[matchedMethods.size()];
    for (int j = 0; j < matchedMethods.size(); ++j) {
        result[j] = matchedMethods.elementAt(j);
    }
    return result;
}

void setReadMethod(Class<?> beanClass, String getterName) {
    boolean result = false;
    Method[] getters = findMethods(beanClass, getterName);
    for (Method element : getters) {
        try {
            setReadMethod(element);
            result = true;
        } catch (IntrospectionException ie) {
        }
        if (result) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

void setWriteMethod(Class<?> beanClass, String setterName)
        throws IntrospectionException {
    boolean result = false;
    Method[] setters = findMethods(beanClass, setterName);
    for (Method element : setters) {
        try {
            setWriteMethod(element);
            result = true;
        } catch (IntrospectionException ie) {
        }
        if (result) {
            break;
        }
    }
}

public PropertyEditor createPropertyEditor(Object bean) {
    PropertyEditor editor;
    if (propertyEditorClass == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!PropertyEditor.class.isAssignableFrom(propertyEditorClass)) {
        // beans.48=Property editor is not assignable from the
        // PropertyEditor interface
        throw new ClassCastException(Messages.getString("beans.48")); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    try {
        Constructor<?> constr;
        try {
            // try to look for the constructor with single Object argument
            constr = propertyEditorClass.getConstructor(Object.class);
            editor = (PropertyEditor) constr.newInstance(bean);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // try no-argument constructor
            constr = propertyEditorClass.getConstructor();
            editor = (PropertyEditor) constr.newInstance();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // beans.47=Unable to instantiate property editor
        RuntimeException re = new RuntimeException(
                Messages.getString("beans.47"), e); //$NON-NLS-1$
        throw re;
    }
    return editor;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded from this page https://code.google.com/p/openbeans/downloads/detail?name=openbeans-1.0.jar the openbean.jar. Then, i imported this jar to the project and changed the references at imported library. 
Then export again the project as .jar library and import in the android project.